# How do I make Gedit run a custom command when I save a certain type of file?

Tags: ruby, gedit

Can I tell Gedit to automatically run a command like `slimrb -p foo.slim foo.html` whenever I save a file ending in .slim?

Comment: Dunno if you can. A less elegant solution may be to bind a key command in gedit to execute such a command (via external tools). The key command may be something close to Ctrl+S so that it's easy to do after each save.